# After making the notebook importable it still gives import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I followed this [link](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html) to make my notebook importable but when I try to import the notebook, it gives me Import Error. This is the actual error that I get:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)  

<ipython-input-23-4e9cc2ac3053> in <module>()  

----> 1 import Notebooks.iPyLoader

ImportError: No module named iPyLoader
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqUKp.png)

I am trying to import the module iPyLoader from the Notebooks directory. As you can see when I run ls command it shows that the module is indeed present. What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

I installed Jupyter Notebook using Anaconda.

Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

ipython --version
5.3.0
jupyter --version
4.3.0
jupyter notebook --version
5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird! 
I tried to reproduce your issue, but without any success:
[image]

Could you please provide more information about your environment:

```
$ ipython --version
$ jupyter --version
$ jupyter notebook version
```

Anyway, pay attention that I have slightly different import error message. Not `No module named iPyLoader`, but `No module name Notebooks.NotExits` -- i.e with a full path. Maybe it will give you a clue.

Comment: ipython --version
5.3.0
jupyter --version
4.3.0
jupyter notebook --version
5.0.0  
Note: If I try to import iPyLoader notebook from outside of the Notebooks directory I get 'ImportError: cannot import name iPyLoader' but if I try to import iPyLoader from the Notebooks directory I get no such file or directory error. 
The sys.executable shows same path '/home/hduser/anaconda2/bin/python' both from notebook and python interpreter. I want to mention that I had previously installed Jupyter through pip because I was getting this same error I removed everything and installed using anaconda.

Comment: And if I try to 'import iPyLoader' in iPyLoader notebook I get this:
iPyLoader.ipynb
iPyLoader.ipynb
importing Jupyter notebook from iPyLoader.ipynb

Comment: " importing Jupyter notebook from iPyLoader.ipynb" -- this message isn't printed to me. Do you use a code from http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html?
You don't use it! It should work without any additional code. At least it works for me that way. Documentation is misleading, I think.
So. Restart your kernel and try import another notebook like any other module.

Comment: Yes I did use all the code in that documentation till it said "After this point, my notebooks should be importable." As you advised I restarted my kernel and tried to import another notebook named TryThis, still no luck. Any other tip?

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot  with `ls` and `import`?

Comment: It seems there is an error in TryThis, but it was imported. Share TryThis, please. I think we are very close to the solution)

Comment: Weird! It should work)
Let try plan B: https://github.com/ipython/ipynb

Comment: NB:  "*All the code in the .ipynb file is executed*, and classes/functions/variables in the top level are available for use."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time man really appreciate it, that worked like a charm albeit I had to uninstall Anaconda2 and reinstall Anaconda 3 as ipynb package that you mentioned only supported python >=3.4.